# firefox: td background image is larger than the size of td despite css settings

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, background-image

I have a table that consists of 3x3 quadratic cells td. css is as following ( #pics is id of the table, .pixcell is a class of the quadratic cell ). The table is inside a container div which is inside the body. I have relative positioning across the whole DOM ( i.e. each element has position:relative and percentage sizing. I have the following problem:

the background image absolutely does not squeeze into the td size in firefox , while it does it in safari ( haven't even started with the other browsers yet!)

another problem: the table doesn't scale to the parent element ( i.e. it extends past the screen size) - in all browsers.

```
    #pics {
background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0);
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
left: 5%;
top:5%;
max-height: 80%;
max-width: 80%;
table-layout: fixed;
height:80%;
width:80%;
```

}

```
    #pics tr {
      margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
height: 33.3%;
width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
```

}

```
    .pixcell {
      position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 33.3%;
    max-height: 33.3%;
    margin: 0px;
     padding:0px;
    background: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

Note: I did go through all the questions i could find and followed all advice , to no avail. I have also tried -moz-background-size: 100% 100%; to no avail. 
Note2: I create my table and assign the background url and class to the td's programmatically (javascript/jquery).

Comment: Provide the `HTML` that goes with it and a fiddle if possible

Comment: HTML is as simple as <div> containing the table , the div has height 100% and relative positioning. I will try to add fiddle but the problem is, this functionality is a part of more complex and extensive functions ( also involving images inside the table and fading in and out). However, if there is a problem with CSS, probably it can be seen without javascript code.